# Ajax call going to the wrong host in my Asp.Net application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, razor

I am trying to make an API call in an ASP.Net application. This is what my AJAX call looks like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/foo/bar",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false
    }).done(function (data) {
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    });
```

However, when I click the button to make this request, I get a 404 back because the request is going to this URL:

https://localhost:44303/foo/bar

The request should be going to the URL below:

https://localhost:44360/api/foo/bar

It's worth noting that I did not write this application, and am somewhat new to Asp.NET applications. I'm seeing other AJAX calls in this application to other API endpoints that look basically identical to mine that are going to the correct host in addition to the correct endpoint. I'm clearly missing a step here, but I have no idea what that might be. This is probably simple to fix. I just don't know the magic words to search for.

Comment: If it should be going to a different port... What port is the page itself served from?

Comment: The page itself is served from port 44303 on my development environment.

Comment: @Inglonias: Then what is telling this AJAX request to use an entirely different port?  Perhaps you meant to use a full URL instead of just a path?

Comment: @david That's the question in a nutshell, isn't it? I don't know what might be doing that. It doesn't seem to be in the JS file itself, and I can't find it elsewhere.

Comment: @Inglonias: Then it's not really clear to me what you're asking.  If you want the `url` parameter of the AJAX request to be `'https://localhost:44360/api/foo/bar'`, have you tried making it that?

Comment: That's all well and good for my local environment, but what about when I deploy it and that host changes?

Comment: @Inglonias: You may need to derive the destination URL from some configuration then.  Any way you look at it, if you want the request to go to a different host then somewhere/somehow you need to *tell it* what that host is.  There's no way for it to just guess.  For the application overall, where/how is that other host's URL known?  In some server-side configuration?

Comment: It looks like I misunderstood the method by which the application is using AJAX. It appears that the other AJAX calls are to the page the user is currently on, with a qualifier of `?handler=whatever` and there are methods like `OnGetWhateverAsync` in the .cshtml.cs file. I'm going to look into this and see if this is how things are working elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by changing my strategy.

It turns out I did not understand how other AJAX calls in my application were being handled. They were being handled using handler methods within the cshtml.cs files for the HTML pages.

I put this call into my JS file:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Home?handler=Foo",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            processData: false
        }).done(function (response) {
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        });
```

And then in my Home.cshtml.cs file, I put this method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetExport()
    {
        _logger.LogError("You did the thing correctly!");
        return StatusCode(418);
    }
```

Now, when I click the button on the webpage, I am getting a 418 error back.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a relative path instead of an absolute path.

---

For ASP.NET applications(WebForms and MVC) we use relative paths only when both client and server and being served together.

In your example, the two different ports suggest that you are running both apps separately. The only way to access *the url of the web-api* is to store the API base url in a global varaible and use it.

Without more context on which sort of client app you are using I cannot point to a specific switching method, but one generic way will be as given below.

app-config.js

```
var environment = { apiBaseUrl: 'https://my-hosted-api-app.net/api/' }
```

app-config.dev.js

```
var environment = { apiBaseUrl: 'https://localhost:44360/api/' }
```

And use it in the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
        url: environment.apiBaseUrl + "foo/bar",
```

---

Additional Info: [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2005079/17447)